# Como alterar o Idioma da IDE Netbeans 11 no Windows 10

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podemos ver na foto da IDE está em Inglês. O compilador também, mas quero modificar para o Português-Brasil.

Verifiquei o arquivo `netbeans.CONFIG` que fica na pasta `C:\Program Files\NetBeans-11.1\netbeans\etc`.

Mas mesmo setando a linha (`netbeans_default_options=`) para `-J-Duser.language=pt -J-Duser.region=BR`, o compilador e a IDE ainda continuam em Inglês.

Comment: Tente baixar ele pelo site já em pt-br.
Tem uma opção de escolher a linguagem lá. No link já esta marcado português tho. LINK: [netbeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/8.0.1/?pagelang=pt_BR)

Comment: Essa versão do seu Link é A 8.0.1 A que estou querendo alterar o valor é da version 11

Comment: https://netbeans-ide.br.uptodown.com/windows/download aqui você tem o link do netbeans 11 em português